# Vectors not colliding with Sprites: p5.play

Tags: javascript, p5.js, p5.play

I am writing a game where you are a "monster" with tentacles which you use to pull yourself  with. I was testing the collision and the tentacle was phasing through the sprite I was using to test. I am using this [code](https://editor.p5js.org/codingtrain/sketches/CvGJFQPLa) as a base and here is my code:

```js
class Segment {
  constructor(x, y, length, angle) {
    this.a = createVector(x, y)
    this.b = createVector(x, y)
    this.length = length
    this.angle = angle
    this.calculateB()
  }
  
  follow(targetX, targetY) {
    const target = createVector(targetX, targetY)
    const direction = p5.Vector.sub(target, this.a)
    this.angle = direction.heading()
    
    direction.setMag(this.length)
    direction.mult(-1)
    this.a = p5.Vector.add(target, direction)
  }
  
  setA(x, y) {
    this.a.set(x, y)
    this.calculateB()
  }
  
  calculateB() {
    const dx = this.length * cos(this.angle)
    const dy = this.length * sin(this.angle)
    this.b.set(this.a.x + dx, this.a.y + dy)
  }
  
  update() {
    this.calculateB()
  }
  
  show(i) {
    const a = this.a
    const b = this.b
    
    stroke(255)
    strokeWeight(i * 4 + 2)
    line(a.x, a.y, b.x, b.y)
  }
}

let monster;
// VARIABLES
let segments = []
const numberOfSegments = 50
const segmentLength = 5
const initialX = 0
const initialY = 0
const initialAngle = 0
let base // Vector with the position of the base
let vertical // Vector at the top, pointing it makes the segments vertical
let target // Vector at which the end of the segments is pointing

// SETUP
function setup() {
  
  new Canvas(400,400,'fullscreen')
  
  base = createVector(width/2, height)
  vertical = createVector(width/2, 0)
  target = createVector(width/2, 0)
  
  for (let i = 0; i < numberOfSegments; i++) {
    const segment = new Segment(
      initialX,
      initialY,
      segmentLength,
      initialAngle
    )
    segments.push(segment)
  }
  
  // later going to attatch tentacle to this but currently using to test collision.
  monster = new Sprite(200,200,30)
  
}

// DRAW
function draw() {
  background(51);
  
  drawLimits()
  calculateTargetXY()
  
  
  
  // Make segments follow their target
  for (let i = 0; i < segments.length; i++) {
    const x = i === 0 ? target.x : segments[i-1].a.x
    const y = i === 0 ? target.y : segments[i-1].a.y
    segments[i].follow(x, y)
    segments[i].update()
  }
  
  // Fix the segments to the base and display them
  for (let i = segments.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    const pos = i === segments.length - 1 ? base : segments[i + 1].b
    segments[i].setA(pos.x, pos.y)
    segments[i].show(i / segments.length)
  }
}

const drawLimits = () => {
  stroke(70)
  strokeWeight(1)
  noFill()
  circle(width/2, height, numberOfSegments * segmentLength * 2) 
}

const calculateTargetXY = () => {
  const ratio = 0.97
  target.x = ratio * target.x + (1 - ratio) * mouseX
  target.y = ratio * target.y + (1 - ratio) * mouseY
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>

        
<script src="https://p5play.org/v3/planck.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://p5play.org/v3/p5play.js"></script>
```

any help is appreciated and I usually use p5.play but I am currently using a hybrid of p5.js (this is my first time using it) and p5.play.

Comment: Basically how do i make the white line collide with the circle in the middle of the screen

Comment: and if thats impossible how do i program something similar to the white line in p5play

Comment: I can't see anywhere in the code where it attempts to check for collision - have you tried to implement it? You should have a serious attempt to do it yourself before opening a stack overflow question about it. SO is a last resort when you've tried but still can't solve a problem yourself, not for when you're not sure where to start off. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have i just removed that code as it did not work and seemed redundant. also i have no idea how to add collision. ive tried adding collision using p5plays collider system (segments.collider = 'd') which did not  work :(. i also googled how to add colliders to vectors in p5.js but nothing seemed to match what i had and tried stuff but that did not work.

Comment: The code that does not work is the most important bit! The point of stack overflow is to help each other figure out why broken code doesn't work. If you don't include your broken code, you're just asking people to write all your code for you, which isn't going to happen. In this scenario the problem is that collision isn't working, but the tentacle stuff is working fine - so why would you show us the tentacle code but not the collision code? Without your collision code it's impossible to help you fix your collision problem!

Comment: Beacause i dont know if the code i wrote is collision code at all

Comment: You're using a very old version of p5.js v0.8.0, you should update to the latest v1.9.1

Comment: @quinton-ashley I’m using CodeHS so I have no idea if I can update it.

Comment: try sending them an email telling them that